# Outdoor activities for shoulder season

Tags: backcountry, shoulder-season

I am in Toronto, Canada. From mid May to mid September, there is a ton to do outdoors. Fishing, hiking, canoeing ,kayaking , sailing, camping etc etc.

In winter, January to March , there is skiing, Nordic skiing,winter camping, ice fishing etc.

What are some outdoor activities that one can enjoy in Months of October, November, December and April?

Comment: Seems to me you can do many of the same activities, you might just get a bit wet from rain.

Comment: Kayaking works until the lakes freeze.

Comment: "Shoulder" season? That's a new one on me.

Comment: I'd never heard of shoulder season either is it a US\Canadian term?

Comment: We also use "shoulder" in Australia to mean either side of peak season. It's often reflected in hotel pricing, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ice skating** is my favourite elusive shoulder season activity. Out here in Banff we'll often get the right conditions in late November for the ponds to freeze over without a snowfall, creating a crystal clear skating surface. 
[image: Ice skating on the Vermillion Ponds in Banff, AB]

But it doesn't happen every year, and it takes just one snowfall to ruin it. Larger lakes take longer to freeze, and some get enough wind that it clears off through December.

[image: Ice skating on Lake Minnewanka, Banff AB]

In April, **whitewater canoeing** in the spring thaw is a popular option (wear a dry suit!) while **hiking** can be done on southern aspects. In Banff you can **downhill ski** until the end of May, while people continue to **ski tour** until the end of June.

Comment: Yes, banff is paradise, I know. If only a programmer could find a decent job there.:)